# Can I use request metadata, like the host domain, in an Azure table storage filter?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a function with an httpTrigger, and I'd like to use the domain and the path (the `route` in the trigger binding) to look up a value in a table store. The function app will have multiple domains pointing to it, so I want to use the request domain as part of the filter.

Filtering based on the route/path works fine, but I can't find any information about using other parts of the request.

How can I provide the request host or URL to the table binding as part of a filter?

Here's my `function.json`:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "route": "{path}",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "redirectRule",
      "type": "table",
      "take": "1",
      "filter": "Host eq '{????}' and Path eq '{path}'",
      "tableName": "RedirectRules",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where I have `{????}`, I'd like to use something like `req.headers.host` (which doesn't work). Is this possible?

Comment: What runtime stack is the function?

Comment: Javascript function on Linux. Is there more detail to the stack than that? Let me know if so!

Comment: I was going to suggest using the IFunctionInvocationFilter interface if you were using the .NET runtime stack to implement a custom OnExecutingAsync filter. I don't know if there is anything similar for the JavaScript runtime stack.